# Window is not getting responsive in small devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my web page, it works perfectly in large devices but it when i check it in small devices i can see extra space and a horizontal scrolling which is not required. I am confused if the table i am using creating this problem or my grid . I am attaching my live website link for view [App](http://god.yobitch.in)

**When you see the live page , in small width screen there is horizontal scroll, I am not getting if table is overflowing or div area, it's just i want to know how to remove that horizontal scroll**

And also providing my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>God Among Computers</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
   scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
   <script  src="script/script.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body background="images/bg.jpg">
    <div class="container">
      <nav style = "background-color: #2980b9; border-color: none;" 
        class="navbar navbar-default">
        </nav>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">

     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="background-color: white;" class="col-xs-7">
                <div class="row" style="padding: 5px;">
                    <center>
                    <h1>I can <img style="width:10%" class="img-responsive"  src="images/read.png"> your Mind</h1></center>
                    <h4>How it works</h4>
                    <ul >
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Take a two digit number, Example : 34 </li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Add the digits. Example: 3+4=7</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Subtract the sum from original number. Example: 34-7=27</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Search this number in emoticon table.</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Remeber the symbol next to your result.</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Concentrate on the found emoticon.</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Click on the mind icon to be amazed.</li>
                        <li style="font-family: 'fonarto'">Want more? Click on Try Again</li>
                        </ul>

                    <center>
                        <img id="result" class="img-responsive"  style="display: none;"><br>

                            <img class="img-responsive" id="refresh" src="images/tryagain.jpg"  style="width: 50%; display: none" onclick="window.location.reload();">
                            <div id="btn">
                            <span style="font-family: 'fonarto'">
           <b>Click Me !!</b></span>

                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="images/mind.png" style="width: 50%;"></div>


                    </center>


                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-sm" style="background-color:white;">
                    <?php

                        $symbol = ['1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'];
                        shuffle($symbol);
                        echo '<tbody><tr>';
                        for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) { 
                                if ($i%9==0) {
                                    echo '<td id = '.$i.'>'.$i.': <img src=images/symbol/'.$symbol[0].'></td>';
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo '<td id = '.$i.'>'.$i. ': <img src=images/symbol/'.$symbol[$i%10].'></td> ';
                                }

                                if($i%5==0){
                                    echo'</tr><tr>';
                                }
                        }   
                        echo '</tbody>';
                    ?>
                    </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Auto Responsive -->
                        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                             style="display:block"
                             data-ad-client="ca-pub-4256692395717993"
                             data-ad-slot="2241707869"
                             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                        <script>
                            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                        </script>
    </div>


    </div>
     </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: please can you tell about which extra space you are talking about

Comment: When you see the live page , in small width screen there is horizontal scroll, I am not getting if table is overflowing or div area, it's just i want to know how to remove that horizontal scroll

Comment: try using 'table-condensed' class in table

Comment: thanx, it worked for me ! Please  give it as answer and i will accept it ... And it would it be good if tell me why that normal table class didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 'table-condensed' class in table

Answer (score 1):

By default minimum size which is the width of bootstrap is 320px. You need to know characteristics of device and browser that is used to view the desired website. Try to get an idea what is native screen resolution of device and test with web mobile tests online or other tools.